# How do I detect line change event in ace editor?

Tags: editor, ace-editor

I am trying to capture a line change event in ace editor. Every time user presses enter the line changes and the console.log shows the current line no. im trying to execute the following code.

```
editor.getSession().getRowLength().on('change', function(event) {
    if (lineno ==1){
        //execute abc}
    else if (lineno==2){
        //execute xyz}
});
```

I get the following error

```
tryit-ide.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: editor.getSession(...).getRowLength(...).on is not a function
at tryit-ide.js:20
at setUp (arch_ace-editor.js?hash=d1163619d62832acc5c961ddb94093c49630a447:78)
at callback (arch_ace-editor.js?hash=d1163619d62832acc5c961ddb94093c49630a447:98)
at arch_ace-editor.js?hash=d1163619d62832acc5c961ddb94093c49630a447:111
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (arch_ace-editor.js?hash=d1163619d62832acc5c961ddb94093c49630a447:53)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the error just says that you are adding event listener on a number. Try

```
editor.session.on('change', function(delta) {
     var lineno = delta.start.row
    if (lineno ==1){
        //execute abc}
    else if (lineno==2){
        //execute xyz}
});
```

Comment: Thank You for replying. Maybe I haven't explained my problem properly. The issue is that the editor executes "abc" on line no everytime something is inserted in the line, whereas I want it to execute it just once when the user enters line 1 and stop execution when the user enters line 2.

Comment: there is no event that fires for line, you need to use the change event and use delta.start.row to findthe line which is changed.

Comment: or do you mean cursor moves to line 1?